# Montar servidor deno-express con deno me da error Argument of type 'String[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[string, string][]'

Tags: javascript, deno

Estoy tratando de levantar un servidor web para servir HTML mediante deno, tenía entendido que se usaba el Fetch API, pero al tratar lanzar tuve que hacer pruebay error para crear un objeto response.

```
import * as express from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NMathar/deno-express/master/mod.ts";

const PORT_NUMBER: number = 8085;
const app: express.App = new express.App();

// Middleware
app.use(express.simpleLog());
app.use(express.bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static_('./'));

// Rutas
app.get('/', (req, res: Response) => {
    let headers = new Array<String>();
    headers["Content-Type"] = ["text/html"];
    res = new Response("<h1>hello world!</h1>", 200, "ok", headers, 1, false);
});

const server = await app.listen(PORT_NUMBER);
console.log("app listening on PORT_NUMBER " + server.port);
```

El error que me arroja es:

```
deno run server.ts
```

> error: TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response)
>
> => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EndHandler'.   Types of parameters 'res' and 'res' are incompatible.
>
> ```
> Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': ok, redirected, statusText, trailer, and 8 more.
>
> app.get('/', (req, res: Response) => {
>
>          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> at file:///C:/Users/RuslanLopez/IdeaProjects/ragaman/server.ts:12:14
> ```
>
> TS7015 [ERROR]: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index
>
> expression is not of type 'number'.
>
> ```
> headers["Content-Type"] = ["text/html"];
>
>         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> at file:///C:/Users/RuslanLopez/IdeaProjects/ragaman/server.ts:14:13
> ```
>
> TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type 'String[]' is not assignable to
>
> parameter of type '[string, string][]'.   Type 'String' is not
>
> assignable to type '[string, string]'.
>
> ```
>  res = new Response("<h1>hello world!</h1>", 200, "ok", headers, 1, false);
>
>                                                        ~~~~~~~
>
> at file:///C:/Users/RuslanLopez/IdeaProjects/ragaman/server.ts:15:60
> ```
>
> Found 3 errors.

Lo que más me turba es el que dice que se esperaba un tipo `[string, string][]`, cosa que no se me ocurre como declarar.

Comment: Intenta hacerlo asincronamente es decir `app.get("/foo", async (req, res) => { foo..})`, me avisas que tal te fue.

Comment: Personalmente me gusta mas [denotrain](https://github.com/Caesar2011/denotrain), no es 100% fiel express ya que trabaja con un contexto que es esencialmente un objeto que contiene la petición, las cookies, etc. y a demas se envía la respuesta simplemente retornando la función, pero te permite trabajar tanto asincronamente como al contrario, un saludo.

Comment: el problema del async es que debe de tener await no es así?

Comment: No necesariamente, pero depende de como esté construido el modulo, puede que los metodos de la clase solo devuelvan promesas pero no lo se a ciencia cierta, por lo que procederé a hacer algunos tests.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo, pasa que en el segundo parámetro del método get o cualquier tipo de petición REST de este modulo, puedo imaginar, se espera una promesa, al pasarle una función de tipo void salta el error mencionado, en fin TypeScript jeje... por lo que solo debes hacer la función asíncrona y listo.

```
app.get("/api/todos", async (req, res) => {
 await res.json([{ name: "Buy some milk" }]);
});
```

Personalmente por esto prefiero [denotrain](https://github.com/Caesar2011/denotrain/blob/master/doc/responses.md) que es muy versátil, permitiéndote trabajar tanto sincrona como asincronamente, incluso puedes ver un que otro modulo disponible en la [lista de terceros](https://deno.land/x) en la [pagina oficial de deno](https://deno.land/) que también te permite  obtener buenos resultados.

**EDIT**: Probando puedo ver que no tienes que usar await para trabajar con el request o el response, por lo que solo el callback (segundo parámetro) de los métodos CRUD deben ser una promesa vacía.

**EDIT**: **Enviando HTML**

Para poder enviar otro tipo de contenido que no estén en los metodos de la respuesta en deno-express, siempre puedes editar el body y trabajar con los headers, ya que no existe el metodo send. El objeto headers en la respuesta es una clase y tiene un par de métodos, en este caso solo utilizamos `append`, observa.

Primero añadimos el tipo de contenido en los headers:

```
res.headers.append("Content-Type","text/html");
```

Y luego editamos el body:

```
res.body = "<h1>hello</h1>";
```

Y listo, debería funcionar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres saber mas sobre  lo que contiene cada cosa solo haz un log del objeto, es lamentable que este modulo no tenga una documentación.

Por cierto, felicitaciones por incursionar y aprender tecnologías realmente innovadoras como lo es Deno que a de mas ya puedes empezar a utilizarlo en producción ¡ya vamos por la versión 1.0! Personalmente no soy fan de TS jajaj pero es lo que hay, un saludo y espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: no quiero servir json, quiero servir html.

Comment: Voy a añadir un edit para ayudarte pero no es la pregunta ojo, podría considerarse como respondida ya de hecho, el response en Json es solo una ejemplificación para que veas como declarar el callback del modulo.

Comment: En ningún momento aclaraste nada acerca de el tipo de dato [string, string][], así que no es ni remotamente útil

Comment: Listo amigo, y es prácticamente lo mismo, los headers son una clase o interface, no he mirado pero no es un objeto por lo que ts te manda un error de que no está esperando un string, un saludo.

Comment: Lo que pusiste ya lo había intentado, body es de solo lectura. Por eso es que estaba tratando de hacer un objeto response. TS2540 [ERROR]: Cannot assign to 'body' because it is a read-only property.
    res.body = "<h1>hello</h1>";

Comment: A ver, a que te refieres con lectura? Estoy efectivamente cambiando el body, se ve reflejado tanto en el navegador como en insomnia, te estoy dando una solución efectiva, si no no lo pusiera, tan si quiera lo probaste? Tambien puedes verlo así console.log(res.toHttpResponse()); y efectivamente hay contenido.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108910/discussion-between-dy-crawford-and-ruslan-lopez).